# Can I get high-speed sync with an iISO-hotshoe Sony body, a Godox speedlight, and a hotshoe adapter?

Tags: adapter, godox, sony-nex, high-speed-sync

Can I get High-Speed Sync (HSS) flash with my Godox 350 in manual mode, using a JJC MSA-10 hot-shoe adapter with my Sony NEX-3K camera's iISO hotshoe?

Answer (score 2):

No. That adapter won't work for HSS. That adapts the iISO hotshoe to an ISO "universal" hotshoe, but that only communicates the sync (fire) signal, not the full hotshoe communication protocol.

What you need to get HSS/TTL with a Godox speedlight is an [iISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IISO_flash_shoe) to [multi-interface hotshoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_Interface_Shoe) adapter, like a Vello HSA-CSASM.